# How to shade the specific cell while exporting the csv file in PHP

Tags: php

Hello am trying to generate and color/shade a specific cell (Month) while exporting the csv file via PHP.  How do i color/shade the Month cell ?

```
/ open the file "file.csv" for writing
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
// save the column headers
fputcsv($file, array('Month', 'Day Date'));

// save each salary Days to the csv file
foreach($salaryDays as $row){
fputcsv($file, $row);
}
// Close the file
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Not sure that will be possible in a CSV

Comment: You don't! `.csv` is a text format.

Comment: Things like that simply aren't supported in CSV files. You would need to be creating an Excel or similar file to be able to use shading/coloring or any other type of formatting.